# 7-ZIP (LZMA) compression for iPhone (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, 7zip, ios

Does anybody know if there is an implementation of 7-Zip (LZMA) that would work on iPhone (iOS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this [7zip port for Mac](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keka/), but I'm not sure if it works on iOS.

Answer (score 11):

I have created an iPhone example app with integrated 7zip LZMA SDK support. You can download it [here](http://www.modejong.com/iOS/). This example is based on LZMA SDK 9.21 beta. It includes only decode functions and the adler checksum logic is disabled at compile time, to improve performance. The example download is an iPhone xcode project file and all needed files.

Comment: how's the performance on a mobile device?

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can use 7zip terminal package if you have ifile installed in your iphone. you can install 7zip from cydia.