# How to unzip/extract 7z compressed files in ios

Tags: iphone, extract, 7zip, compression

I need to **unzip/extract 7z compressed files in ios**, Can anyone say the libraries used to do this,where are those libraries available to download.I there any sample project to do this ,let me know

Comment: possible duplicate of [7-ZIP (LZMA) compression for iPhone (iOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169198/7-zip-lzma-compression-for-iphone-ios)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, do you know how to unzip .xz files which uses LZMA2 algorithm

Answer (score 2):

7-Zip Lzma SDK - is a multi-language SDK for handling 7-zip files.  Mo Dejong has created an example demonstrating how to use the LZMA SDK to decompress 7-zip libraries on iOS devices.  You can find the example on his website [here](http://www.modejong.com/iOS/#ex7).

Comment: I have even contacted Apple support about the same issue and it seems there is nothing included in the SDK to deal with zip files.

Comment: Here is a github link for an iOS port with very large file support https://github.com/mdejong/lzmaSDK

Answer (score 1):

iOS9 comes with LZMA support (encoder until level 6, decoder all levels). Of course this only helps if you *just* need the compression – if you absolutely need to read the 7z archive / container format you'll need an external library.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/Compression/index.html